# Angular DOM control not working in Firefox but works OK in Chrome and IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created a simple page to test DOM control and scroll bar function.  The object of the test is to 1) watch for a change in a scope variable (in this case $scope.clicks or catch a mouse click to change the size of the inline SVG to watch the scroll bar reactions.  It works fine with Chrome and IE11.  Firefox seems to not resolve either document.getElementById or angular.element(document.querySelector).

```js
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.handleClick = function ($event) {
        var w1 = document.getElementById('svg-head');
        var cH = w1.clientHeight + 20;
        var cW = w1.clientWidth + 20;
        $scope.myHeight = cH;
        $scope.myWidth = cW;
        $scope.viewString = '0 0 ' + cH + ' ' + cW;

    };
    $scope.clicks = 0;
    $scope.addclicks = function () {
        $scope.clicks += 1;
    };
    $scope.$watch("clicks", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        var w2 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#svg-head'))[0];
        var cH = w2.clientHeight + 20;
        var cW = w2.clientWidth + 20;
        $scope.myHeight = cH;
        $scope.myWidth = cW;
    });
});
```

```css
html body {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.div1 {
    position:  relative;
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;

}

.div2 {
    position: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

svg {
    position: inherit;
    float: inherit;
    border: 3px solid green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html ng-app="miniapp">
    <title>H & W</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div id="div0">
    <button ng-click="addclicks()">clickme</button>
    <div class="div1 container" id="one" ng-click="handleClick($event)" resize>
        <div class="div2 container" id="two">
            <svg
                    class="svg-class"
                    ng-style="{ 'width' : myWidth, 'height' : myHeight }"
                    id="svg-head" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <defs>
                </defs>

                <g>
                    <rect
                            height=50
                            width=125
                            id="rect-1"
                            style="fill: yellow;"
                            >
                    </rect>
                    <rect
                            x="200"
                            y="200"
                            height=50
                            width=125
                            id="rect-2"
                            style="fill: blue;"
                            >
                    </rect>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <prog>{{clicks}} - {{myHeight}} x {{myWidth}}</prog>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I confirmed that the code snipped works in Chrome, but not IE11. It must be how the snipped it managed to prevent IE11 from working correctly.

Comment: Hi , Have you found the solution for this issue ?